# Spring Boot 404 Error with Simple Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to make a simple Spring Boot Application with the simple controller (Restful controller) where the function is returning the String that is to be printed on the Web page. But I am facing a problem where I am getting 404 error every time. In my views, I am setting up the application right. I have just used spring-boot-starter-web as the dependency.

Application file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

And I know @SpringBootApplication automatically take all the annotation.

Comment: In which package UserController and Demo1Application exists?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: @AnilKumarAthuluri thank you so much I figured the mistake.

Comment: @RishabhSharma  Glad my answer helped you !

Answer (score 1):

Either your controller class needs to be in or sub package of SpringBoot Application class or the package in which controller class exists needs to be scanned explicitly using @ComponentScan to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the structure of your project?, I believe the problem Spring is not finding your userController, @SpringBooApplication use the @ComponentScan how is in charge to search for all the spring annotations un your code, so I believe is something

Answer (score 0):

Need to add @ComponenScan the resquest to http:localhost:8080/api should return "Hello" if you need to add a path http:localhost:8080/user/api do as follow:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
```